# Custom shipping method with table rate

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

I am trying to begin developing two custom shipping methods for Magento but have become stuck.

I would like to create one for "Standard" delivery which will be calculated using Weight Vs Distance.

The second module will be "Priority processing" which will also be calculated using weight Vs distance but needs to have an additional charge.

I quess my question is are there any tutorials or skeleton modules that I can use for this? i have created custom methods in the past but I have never been able to add the ability to add an additional fee or calculate weight and distance as most are based on the "Flat fee" type of method.

I would be grateful for any tips and I will gladly share the module(s) once I get them working.

Comment: at least for the standard method you may not need to create it. Table rate already supports weight vs destination. I think you can use that. Just fill in the table.

Comment: @Marius I currently have Table rate setup but I need to create two custom modules based on the Table rate functionality then add an additional fee for "Priority processing" still a bit lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrixrates which is a free module by WebShopApps supports multiple shipping methods being displayed. Seems like that would perfectly fit your needs here, you just set the rules for both standard and priority.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this as the basis of my module and I think it may suffice. I will post back if I get stuck

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module